# How to find search records from multiple tables in MySQL related in One to Many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have a Job Portal Project and my Tables in Job Portal Database are

**Candidate Table**

| candidate_id | email | education | candidate_type | f_name | l_name | DOB | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sid@abc.com | bachelor | student_CA | sid | patil | 05/06/1999 | ########## |
| 2 | sid2@abc.com | master | qualified_CA | sid2 | patil2 | 06/05/1999 | ########## |
| 3 | sid3@abc.com | master | experienced_CA | sid3 | patil3 | 06/05/1999 | ########## |

**Skills Table**:
In this table skill of all the candidates are entered in One to Many related to the Candidates Table

| id | candidate_id | skill_name | verified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | python | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | SQL | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | JAVA | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | CSS | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | SQL | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | python | 1 |

**Papers Table** : This table contains papers cleared by the Candidates in CA Exams its also One to Many Relationship with Candidate Table

| id | paper | pass_year | candidate_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | accouting | 2015 | 1 |
| 2 | comapny law | 2016 | 1 |
| 3 | direct taxation | 2017 | 1 |
| 4 | company law | 2020 | 2 |
| 5 | accouting | 2018 | 2 |

Now the employer can filter candidates by candidate_type, specific skills, specific papers cleared:
Employer will fill the below Form

```
<form action="/company/filterCandidates">
           <select name="candidate_type">
                <option value="student">Student</option>
                <option value="qualified_ca">qualified_ca</option>
                <option value="experienced_ca">experienced_ca</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="skills" placeholder="comma separated skills required">
            <input type="text" name="papers" placeholder="comma separated papers required">
            <button name="submit">Filter Candidates</button>
        </form>
```

After submitting the form In filterCandidates Model

```
//Getting employer posted data
$candidate_type = $this->input->post('candidate_type');
$papers = $this->input->post('reqPapers');
$skills = $this->input->post('reqSkills');

//Creating a string to put in where clause
$skillWhereIN = "";
if(trim($skills) != ""){
$skillsArray = explode(',', $skills);
$skillString = 'WHERE skill_name IN (';
$count = 0;
foreach ($skillsArray as $item) {
    if($count != 0){
        $skillString .= ',';
    }
    $skillString .= '\''.$item.'\'';
    $count++;
}
$skillString .= ')';
}
//skillString = ('skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3')


$papersWhereIn = "";
$papersArray = explode(',', $papers);
$papersString = 'WHERE paper IN (';
$count = 0;
foreach ($papersArray as $item) {
    if($count != 0){
        $papersString .= ',';
    }

    $papersString .= '\''.$item.'\'';
    $count++;
}

$papersString .= ')';
}
//$paperString = ('accounting', 'direct taxation', etc..)    



$sql = "SELECT * FROM
      (
        (
          SELECT candidate_id as sc_id, COUNT(candidate_id) as skillMatches FROM skills ".$skillWhereIN." 
        GROUP BY candidate_id
         ) AS skills 
     JOIN  
        (
         SELECT candidate_id AS pc_id, COUNT(candidate_id) as paperMatches 
         FROM actuarial_papers ".$papersWhereIn." 
         GROUP BY candidate_id
        ) AS papers 
      WHERE skills.sc_id=papers.pc_id
       ) 
       JOIN users
       WHERE candidate_type=".$candidate_type;



 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
```

In the above situation if the Employer Wants to filter for Qualified_CA then I don't need to search for papers cleared table because qualified_CA has passed all the papers. When the employer selects to search for the qualified CA i want to only Join skills table and the candidates table and find the records having candidate_type = qualified_CA:

Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: **Warning**: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What if I use strip_tags function on all the inputs. Will that be okay to prevent SQL injections
Or mysqli_real_escape function

Comment: You are using the CI framework and should read about the [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html), which helps you to produce secure queries